# SELinux alert: Why is the start chopped off the process name?

Tags: systemd, selinux

I have a service `hdparm-noapm.service` with `ExecStart=/ansible-managed/sourcejedi.hdparm-noapm/hdparm.sh`.  Thanks to SELinux, it is denied.  The SELinux error popup (sealert) says

- The source process: (dparm.sh)
- Attempted this access: execute
- On this file: hdparm.sh

Why is the first letter chopped off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVC shows the same process name if I find it in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  So this is not a bug in the GUI.

There are two points here.  Firstly, the systemd process forked for the service "renames" itself before `exec`uting the program.

Secondly, it doesn't allocate any extra space for the process name, so it can't be any longer than `/sbin/init`.  (The behaviour in the face of the kernel `init=` option is left as an exercise for the reader).  The end of the program name is considered more interesting to preserve than the start, since "the first bit might just be 'systemd-'".

According to the TODO, this will be resolved by "PR_SET_PROCTITLE_AREA if it becomes available in the kernel", i.e. it would avoid the need to truncate the process name.

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/782c925f7fa2e6e716ca9ac901954f3349d07ad8/src/core/execute.c#L1237